# What does ROC-EER in percent stand for?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, roc

Ive tried to understand what the ROC Curve represents and what EER (Equal Error Rate) means. And I somehow think I got to understand some of the explanations I read on the internet and videos I watched and papers I read. But I still cant get a grip on what it means in my particular case.

I am reading a paper on face verification. The described method is trained and tested on the "Labeled Faces in the Wild"-Benchmark. That benchmark offers a standard dataset for comparison to other face-verification-methods. It essentually is a huge database of image-pairs which each depict the same or different persons. The methods at hand should now tell if the depicted persons on these image-pairs are the same or different people. The machine learned method is evaluated with a measure called ROC-EER and the score/result is stated in percentage. And they also evaluated by doing a 10-fold cross validation (which I actually do understand and know what is being done and why)

For example: ROC-EER, %: 89.5

So I just dont know what that 89% should tell me? 89% of what is what? And how does that value correlates to the 10-fold cross validation procedure?

And I even dont know If I am missing some information for you to answer a complete question...I feel a bit lost here :)

Comment: Please, could you link the paper and/or some explanation of EER? I haven't met the term before, although I could make guesses what the term may mean...

Comment: The paper can be found here https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=b53IVI69LujnywOQ7IHAAw&url=http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vedaldi/assets/pubs/simonyan13fisher.pdf&ved=0CB8QFjAB&usg=AFQjCNEGK-VvL591UZ5tcOlLxrxCNKV3lg&sig2=g4DP_wkLHL_Sr6fZiu-pGw and the explanations in question are on page 6 and the table on page 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paper you link explains ROC-EER as

> Receiving Operating Characteristic Equal Error Rate
>   (ROC-EER), which is the accuracy at the ROC operating point
>   where the false positive and false negative rates are equal

So the EER is a way to fix the working point (= threshold for deciding the class) for an actual classifier on the ROC.

So the 89% you quote are then the overall accuracy if you fix the threshold according to the ROC-EER method.

Cross validation is the method ("measurement schedule") how they measured the 89%